# javascript file code is not working when it attached by createElement

Tags: javascript, html

I created script element using createElement and I can see the script tag is added with src in html when I checked it in browser. But js file code is not working on the page.

```
function getStudents() {
    var source = document.createElement('script');
    source.src = url;
    var element = document.getElementById('srcs');
    element.appendChild(source);
}
```

Comment: any *errors* in the console?

Comment: Hi tensae selam. Welcome to StackOverflow!. Did you consider that the inserted javascript might have executed before the page is completely loaded?

Comment: no error in the console.

Comment: @Ahmad Thanks,  How can I execute it after the page loaded?